# Preventing Linux from adding file into memory cache?

Tags: linux, caching, memory, file-io, linux-kernel

I hope you've all seen the wonderful site, Linux Ate My Ram. This is usually great, but it presents a problem for me. I have a secure file that I'm decrypting with `gpg` and then reading into memory to process. The unencrypted file is deleted a short time later, but I do **NOT** want that decrypted file to be saved in Linux's in-memory file cache.

Is there a way to explicitly prevent a file from being saved from Linux's cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Use `gpg -d`, which will cause GPG to output the file to STDOUT, so then you can have it all in memory.

Depending on how paranoid you are, you may want to use [mlock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) as well.

Comment: +1 to this answer. If you truly want to be safe you should prevent the page containing your secret text from being swapped to disk by using mlock/mlockall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did know about `gpg -d` but for odd environment reasons I need to write the file out to disk, so this doesn't quite help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really need gpg's output to be a file, you could put that file on a [ramfs](http://wiki.debian.org/ramfs) file system.  The file's contents will only exist in non-swappable memory pages.

You can attach a ramfs file system to your tree by running (as root):

```
mount none /your/mnt/point -t ramfs
```

You may have also heard of *tmpfs*.  It's similar in that its files have no permanent storage and generally exist only in RAM.  However, for your use, you want to avoid this file system because tmpfs files can be swapped to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Shred the file as you delete it.

```
shred -u $FILE
```

Granted, it doesn't directly answer your question, but I still think it's a solution---whatever's living in the cache is now randomly-generated garbage. :-)

Comment: I was about to say something about how shred doesn't guarantee proper function on journaled file systems, but since you're only interested in flushing the in-memory cache, maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: Which, as `shred(1)` will tell you, doesn't necessarily purge the file from disk when used with NFS, a journaling FS, or a RAID array.

Comment: @Nathan Kidd: You may be right, but leaving sensitive data on disk rather than in RAM is a much greater security risk.

Comment: @larsmans: he specifically asked about the disk *cache*. Of course in the bigger security picture it was the wrong question. :)

Comment: Hi guys, I sort of assumed that the file would be securely deleted as well, so thanks for the heads up on shred.

Comment: The OP could combine this answer with [Karmastan's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009055/preventing-linux-from-adding-file-into-memory-cache/5013162#5013162) - put the file on a ramfs, and remove it from the ramfs with `shred`.